# Unexpected line while set background image for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-image, uisearchbar

I got an unexpected line while set background image for UISearchBar,

[image]

The above attached the image shows my issue. Any help will appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please attach image used

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question,
It was problem with the image size.